# Get Specific Length of String in DTL template

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I have a CharField in model that can contains String of any length upto 1000...

```
details = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

How can I get the String of specific length(say 10) in my template?

```
{{ details|10 }}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Jinja2 and not Django template language?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, I am using DTL, Checkout Edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter.

```
{{ details|slice:":10" }}
```